# ktable-ktable joined data from the topic disappeared after few minutes

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am running the program that joins the ktable with another ktable(inner join) and write it to the output topic. When I executed the program, everything worked fine. I could see the joined data in the kafka logs. but after few minutes the data in the log files disappeared. the 00000000xxx.log file became zero bytes. Is the data moved somewhere else? is there any configuration setting I need to do. I am observing this behavior only for the topics that i am using for creating ktables. any idea why the data is disappearing from the topics after few minutes? Thanks for the help.

the program i am running is from 
https://github.com/ftrossbach/crossing-the-streams/blob/master/src/main/java/de/codecentric/kafka/streams/InnerJoinTable.java

Comment: I your topic configures with compaction or retention time? What is the timestamps of your data? What is your retention time (if any)? If data has timestamps older than retention time, the broker would delete the data.

Comment: Thank you so much Matthias for pointing out. Yes , I have data records with timestamp of 8000ms. after changing the sample data events timestamps then it worked. But I am curious to know how kafka determine to delete the data if i have multiple timestamps in my event data records. Could you please point out me any details or document that explains this prcess.

Comment: Data is deleted by "segments" (segment size is configurable). If all records in a segment have timestamp older than current time minus retention time, the segment is dropped.

Comment: Still I am facing the issue. I have 2 topics View, Click events. I created 2 Ktables for these topics and joined by crelID and streaming the joined data to the topic VIewClick. I see the data properly. After few minutes the .log files become zero. I observed that the log files are renamed to .log.delete and then becomes 0 bytes. I am producing the sample data as   ViewEvent as crelId=1, eventType=View, createdTime=1530579921    ClickEvent as crelId=1, eventType=Click, createdTime=1530579921. I do have custom serdes for these events as well. Not sure how to fix this issue. retention time as 7d.

Comment: Not sure... Maybe try to enable DEBUG logging to figure out why the broker rolls a segment.